# Ruby methods called at top of classes

Tags: ruby

I've seen this a lot in Ruby (started using Ruby for the first time a couple years ago):

```
class MyAwesomeClass

  another_method

  def initialize; end 
end
```

And I can't get my head around what type of method `another_method` is...

Looking at examples, it's sometimes declared as a class method, but usually you call class methods in your code like this:

`AnotherClass.another_method`

And most importantly you call your methods regardless if they are from another class, module, or inherited class inside another method of your class you use them. For example:

```
module SomeModule
  def some_method; end
end

class AnotherClass
  private

  def another_method; end
end

class YetAnotherClass
  self.yet_another_method; end
end

class MyAwesomeClass < AnotherClass
  include SomeModule

  def initialize
    some_method # method from my included module
    another_method # method inherited from AnotherClass
    YetAnotherClass.yet_another_method # class method called directly
  end

end
```

So what are these methods that can be called at the top of a class and NOT called inside of another method as my examples above?

Are you able to just call class methods inside another class (that it inherits from) outside of your method calls?

Comment: `MyClass` or `MyAwesomeClass`?

Comment: I've updated the names... so to show the different examples I'm used to vs. the question I have with the method called outside of another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be easier to understand by looking at it in action.

```
# Step 1
# Run this in IRB
class MyClass
  def self.another_method
    puts "Executed when class is loaded to memory"
  end
end


# Step 2
# Now when you run the following in IRB after that, its going to execute the
#   class method which was defined in its parent class (MyClass)
class MyAwesomeClass < MyClass
  another_method # Executed ONCE when the class is loaded to memory for the first
  def initialize; end 
end


# Now if you instantiate MyAwesomeClass though, it will not print the same as of
#   Step 2 as class method :another_method already has been executed when class
#   was loaded
awesome1 = MyAwesomeClass.new
```

The body of a class will be interpreted and executed sequentially & behaves much like you'd expect it inside an instance method. Try putting a `puts "Hello World"` in the body of your class definition like so:

```
class MyClass
  # Executes when the class is defined in IRB(Loaded to memory)
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

Answer (score 7):

> I can't get my head around what type of method `another_method` is...

There is only one type of method in Ruby: every method in Ruby is an instance method of some module. There is no other type of method.

We may sometimes *talk about* "class methods" or "singleton methods", but that is just a convenient way of talking about a particular way to *use* methods. The methods themselves are no different.

*Every* method in Ruby is an instance method of some module. The question is simply: which module?

We are sometimes *talking about* class methods, but class methods don't really exist. Class methods are simply singleton methods of an object that happens to be an instance of the [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html) class.

There is absolutely no difference between

```rb
Foo = ''
def Foo.bar; end
```

and

```rb
class Foo; end
def Foo.bar; end
```

and

```rb
module Foo; end
def Foo.bar; end
```

We *call* the first one a "singleton method", the second one a "class method", and the third one a "module function", but there is actually no difference between the three. The only difference is that the first object is an instance of the [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) class, the second object is an instance of the `Class` class, and the third object is an instance of the [`Module`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html) class, that's it.

Actually, I must confess something: I lied. I wrote that class methods are simply singleton methods of an object that happens to be an instance of the `Class` class, but in reality … singleton methods don't exist either.

A singleton method is simply a boring old normal instance method of the *singleton class*.

There is no difference between

```rb
foo = ''
def foo.bar; end
```

and

```rb
foo = ''
class << foo
  def bar; end
end
```

There you have it: singleton methods are actually just instance methods of the singleton class, class methods are actually just instance methods of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of the `Class` class, module functions are actually just instance methods of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of the `Module` class.

It's just that "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of the `Class` class" is annoying to say and write all the time, so we say "class method" instead, *knowing full well that there is no such thing*.

> Looking at examples, it's sometimes declared as a class method, but usually you call class methods in your code like this:
>
> `AnotherClass.another_method`

Again, there *is no such thing* as a class method. There is exactly one kind of method, and they are always called the same way:

```rb
receiver.method(args)
```

If the `receiver` is `self`, then you can leave it out, and if you have no arguments, you can leave them out, too.

> And most importantly you call your methods regardless if they are from another class, module, or inherited class inside another method of your class you use them.

That is not true.

In fact, in *your own example*, you are calling two methods outside of a method body: [`Module#private`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private) and [`Module#include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-include), and you seem to have no trouble with those. Other methods that I am *sure* you have already called outside of a method body are [`Module#attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor), [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require), or [`Kernel#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts). In fact, in simple scripts, there is often not a single method definition body at all.

> So what are these methods that can be called at the top of a class and NOT called inside of another method as my examples above?

They are instance methods just like any other instance methods, there is absolutely nothing special about them.

> Are you able to just call class methods inside another class (that it inherits from) outside of your method calls?

Since class methods don't exist, and these are simply instance methods just like every other instance method, the method lookup algorithm is of course also just the method lookup algorithm for instance methods:

1. Start with the private internal hidden `__klass__` pointer of the receiver. If you can't find the method there …
2. Get the private internal hidden `__superklass__` pointer and repeat.

And that's it. (Yes, okay, there is a tiny bit more to it: if you come to a point where there is no `__superklass__` pointer, then you try again with [`method_missing`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) and the name of the method as an argument, and if you also cannot find *that*, then you [`raise`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) a [`NoMethodError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html).)

So, let's try that in your example:

```rb
class MyAwesomeClass
  another_method
end
```

Okay, first off: what is the receiver? Well, if no receiver is given, then the receiver is always implicitly `self`. Now, what is `self` here?

A ha! That is actually the most important question in Ruby, always. At *any point* in Ruby, you must always know what `self` is.

Well, we know that inside of a method body, `self` is the receiver of the message send. So, we can guess: what would make the most sense for `self` inside of a class definition. The class itself, of course! Let's test that:

```rb
what_is_self = class MyAwesomeClass
  self
end

p what_is_self
# MyAwesomeClass
```

Well, looks like we're right. Okay, we know the receiver of the message send is `MyAwesomeClass`, so what is the first step in our algorithm? We get the private internal hidden `__klass__` pointer.

We cannot actually do that in Ruby (it is a private internal hidden implementation detail of the Ruby implementation). But let me assure you that is pretty much always going to be the *singleton class*. (There are some objects which cannot have singleton classes, and some Ruby implementations optimize the creation of singleton classes so that they are only created when needed, but for all intents and purposes, we can assume that the `__klass__` pointer is *always* the singleton class.)

We look inside the singleton class, and we find no definition of the method `another_method`. So, we move to the second step of the algorithm: we get the `__superklass__` of the singleton class.

The `__superklass__` of the singleton class is usually going to be the `class` of the object. So, in this case, the object is `MyAwesomeClass`, which is a class, so the `class` of `MyAwesomeClass` and the `__superklass__` of the singleton class is going to be `Class`.

Again, we look inside `Class` and we don't find `another_method`. Ergo, we get `Class`'s `__superklass__`, which is `Module`. We also don't find `another_method` here, so we move on to `Object`, which also doesn't have `another_method`.

Now, it gets interesting again, because `Object`'s `__superklass__` pointer is actually `Kernel` and not `BasicObject` as you might have thought. (More precisely, it is an *include class* which shares its method table with the `Kernel` module, since `Kernel` is not a class at all and thus cannot be a superclass.)

`Kernel` also doesn't have a method named `another_method`, so we get `Kernel`'s `__superklass__` (again, technically we are talking about an *include class* that proxies `Kernel` and not `Kernel` itself), which is `BasicObject`. Finally, `BasicObject` does not *have* a `__superklass__`.

Which means we start aaaaaaaaaaaall the way back from step #1 again, but this time *as-if* you had written

```rb
class MyAwesomeClass
  method_missing(:another_method)
end
```

We do the whole song-and-dance again, and we also never find a method until we get to the very top, to `BasicObject`, which has a `method_missing` that roughly looks like this:

```rb
class BasicObject
  def method_missing(meth, *args)
    raise NoMethodError, "undefined method `#{meth}' for #{inspect}", meth, args, receiver: self
  end
end
```

So, if you want your call to `another_method` to *not* fail, it needs to be defined *anywhere* along the whole chain we just walked up:

- In `MyAwesomeClass`'s singleton class
- In a module that `MyAwesomeClass` extends
- In `Class`
- In a module that `Class` includes
- Or in a module included by that module
- In `Module`
- In a module that `Module` includes
- Or in a module included by that module
- In `Object`
- In `Kernel`
- Or another module that `Object` includes
- Or in a module that `Kernel` includes
- In `BasicObject`
- In a module that `BasicObject` includes
- Or in a module included by that module
- Or maybe the Ruby implementation you are using has an implementation-specific superclass of `BasicObject` (e.g. MacRuby has Objective-C's `NSObject` as the superclass of `BasicObject`)

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate difference between different type of methods, consider this example:

```rb
class Foo
  puts 'method called outside of method'

  def initialize
    puts 'initialize called'
  end

  def instanse_method
    puts 'instance method called'
  end

  def self.clazz_method
    puts 'class method called'
  end
end

Foo
foo = Foo.new
foo.instanse_method
Foo.clazz_method
```

What will be the output?

```
method called outside of method
initialize called
instance method called
class method called
```

> So what are these methods that can be called at the top of a class and NOT called inside of another method as my examples above?

As you can see, any method can be called before `initialize` method. It's executed when class is loaded.

Just calling

```rb
Foo
```

would be sufficient enough to output:

```rb
method called outside of method
```

(but notice that it was not called multiple times)

> Looking at examples, it's sometimes declared as a class method, but usually you call class methods in your code like this: AnotherClass.another_method

It's like static function in PHP. In my example, it's `Foo#clazz_method`.

> And most importantly you call your methods regardless if they are from another class, module, or inherited class inside another method of your class you use them

Usually, you have to include a file that define another class before using its method. But most frameworks like Ruby on Rails, have already built-in autoloading system, so it looks like it's working magically without explicit `require` or `include`. But there are times when RoR does not know where your custom classes are. In this case, you have to require the file explicitly before you use it. Well, usually in the beginning of the file.